# How to Create variables at runtime and what was its scope in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

i m getting string e.g.`('1','2','7','12')` from database & i want to query sqlserve i.e.

`select subject_nme from subject where subjid=1 && subjid=2 && subjid=7`

using the intgers from string.For querying i need to create dynamic variables to store the subjid into them and use them.
THANX

Comment: You need to tell us more, are you getting those values in a string array or its just one place string ? also post some C# code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Does the string really contain all the punctuation? Do you *have* to store the data that way rather than in a more sensible form? How would you expect a single `subjid` to be 1 *and* 2 *and* 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select subject_nme from subject where subjid in ('1','2','7','12')
```

Comment: The way comparison is done in OP, subjid is integer, this query will fail.

Comment: @Habib.OSU even if the subjid field is an int, my script will work (I just did a quick test). You can even mix it up, like in ('1',2,'3')